# "Ikkigomi"? Single comment in Japanese

Tags: words, definitions, nouns

At least that's what I think is being said, "ikkigomi". It means like "single comment" or "impressions" or something, but I don't know how it's written in Japanese. If someone could enlighten/correct me as to what the word(s) would be.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean 意気込み(Ikigomi in Romaji, いきごみ in Hiragana). 意気込み means your enthusiasm trying to do something.

意気込み is sometimes used like "今の意気込みをお願いします。" which means "Tell me your enthusiasm to try this." This phrase is often heard some TV program, say a sports player is asked this question for his/her short comment on something about to try.